# Progress Block runs too many times - swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am using this block to bring in UImages from Parse.

```
for object in objects {
    let thumbNail = object["StaffPic"] as PFFile

    thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)


        }

        }, progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt) -> Void in
            self.logoImages.append(self.image)
    })
}
```

problem is, that it runs the ProgressBlock 6 times (if there is 6 images in the query). I need it to run the progressBlock ONCE when its all done.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `progressBlock` of [`PFFile`'s `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:progressBlock:`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:progressBlock:) is used to get the progress of the individual files being downloaded, not as a way to know when all the downloads have completed. It could easily be called *more* than 6 times even when downloading just a single file. You definitely shouldn't be appending `self.image` to `self.logoImages` there, that should be done in the result block just after you create `image` from `imageData`.

```
for object in objects {
    let thumbNail = object["StaffPic"] as PFFile

    thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
            self.logoImages.append(image)
        }
    }, progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt) -> Void in
        // Update your UI with download progress here (if needed)
    })
}
```

Now, you seem to be asking for a way to know when all of those downloads have completed. I would use [dispatch groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_async) for that. The basic steps are:

1. Create a `dispatch_group_t`
2. For each download:

   1. Call `dispatch_group_enter`
   2. Do the download
   3. Call `dispatch_group_leave` when the download is complete
3. Call `dispatch_group_notify` with a block that should be called when your downloads are complete.

It would look something like this:

```
let downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()

for object in objects {
    let thumbNail = object["StaffPic"] as PFFile

    dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)

    thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
            self.logoImages.append(image)

            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }
    }, progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt) -> Void in
        // Update your UI with download progress here (if needed)
    })
}

dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // This will be called when all your downloads are complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is meant for asynchronous periodic update, so you could update a progress indicator or something. So you get an update periodically as data comes in... if you really only want to know when it is done, then I suggest only doing your action when `percentDone == 100`...

```
    progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt) -> Void in
            if(percentDone==100)
            {
                self.logoImages.append(self.image)
            }
    })
```

Comment: of course this is `Parse` dependent, as I don't know anything about that library, who knows maybe that could even happen more than once, and maybe there is a better way, like registering a callback, or polling an object for completion... I don't know, I am just guessing based on what you have posted.